# My asp.net mvc web application will always check if the request is authnticated or not

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following Action method:-

```
[Authorize]
[RequireHttps]
[CheckUserPermissions(Action = "Read", Model = "Server")]
    public class ServerController : Controller
    {
        Repository repository = new Repository();

[OutputCache(CacheProfile = "NoCache")]
        public ActionResult Index(string searchTerm = "", int page = 1, string sort = "",int? pagesize=null)
```

now i wanted to test , how the Index action method will behave if we remove any authentication checks. so i remove all the filters that will check if the user is authenticated or not as follow:-

```
   // [Authorize]
    [RequireHttps]
  //  [CheckUserPermissions(Action = "Read", Model = "Server")]
        public class ServerController : Controller
        {
            Repository repository = new Repository();

   // [OutputCache(CacheProfile = "NoCache")]
            public ActionResult Index(string searchTerm = "", int page = 1, string sort = "",int? pagesize=null)
```

But the result i get is that if the user will try to access the Index action method , he still will be redirected to the login view !! can anyone advice what is causing the request to be redirected to the logic view,, although i have remove all the related filters ?
Thanks

Comment: Could you ensure that **web.config** *(one at root and one inside Views folder)* doesn't have **authorization** tag?

Comment: i have these authentication and authorization tags inside web.config.<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880"/>
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?"/>
      <allow users="*"/>
    </authorization>

Comment: could these be causing the issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
i have these authentication and authorization tags inside web.config.
<authentication mode="Forms"> 
   <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880"/> 
</authentication> 
<authorization> 
   <deny users="?"/> 
   <allow users="*"/> 
</authorization>
```

Yes, authorization tag is the problem.

If your application is MVC only *(not mixed with Web Form)*, you should not use **authorization** tag in web.config.

### Solution

Remove authorization tag (and leave authentication tag only).

Comment: yes i am using asp.net mvc only? but why this is a problem ? can you advice please ?

Comment: @johnG The authorization tag is not necessary because if you want to lock down all resources in your web app then you can apply a global filter. Or if you want to lock down a specific controller then apply it to the controller.

Comment: @johnG You should not use **authorization** tag inside **web.config in MVC project**, because MVC uses routes and doesn't map to physical file like Web Form. It'll open a security hole.

Comment: ok i removed the authorization tag from the web.config but this did not change anything , and still users are going to be redirected to login page even when no [Authorize] attribute is mentioned ?? can you advice?

Comment: Search in all **web.configs**, and make sure there is no **authorization** tag.

Comment: ok i have closed the visual studio and re-open it ,, seems it was caching the old web.config .. now when i removed the Authorization it is working well... so as a conclusion if i am using asp.net mvc , then i should never declare Authorization tag in web.config ?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check if you or the framework has added a FilterConfig file in your App_Start folder.  There may be a Global Authorize Attribute that is being assigned.

Comment: i already check this and the FilterConfig  only register the defualt filter for Error Handling...